# Correct usage of 'if !empty' for multiple post values

Tags: php

Before completing registration I wan't to check if all submitted post values aren't empty. The POST values will be assigned to the variables only when all input fields have been filled. Else missingFields will be displayed in the URL.

So what I came up with seems to work, however I wonder if the !empty is actually going through all post values, just like individually checking all post values with !empty. If not, what should be changed?

```
if (!empty($_POST['first']) && ($_POST['last']) && ($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['password'])) {
    // If the posts contain any values, assign them to these variables.
    $first_name = $_POST['first'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last'];
    $mail_address = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hash = hash('sha256', $password); // Password will be hashed.

    // Check if the email already exists or not.
    $existingUser = 'SELECT * FROM account WHERE sMailaddress = :mail';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($existingUser);
    $stmt->execute([
        ':mail' => $mail_address
    ]);

    // When no results are found, insert values into database.
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        $registerUser = 'INSERT INTO account (sFirstname, sLastname, sMailaddress, sPassword)
        VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :mail_address, :pass)';

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($registerUser);
        $stmt->execute([
            ':first_name' => $first_name,
            ':last_name' => $last_name,
            ':mail_address' => $mail_address,
            ':pass' => $hash
        ]);

        header('Location: template/authentication.php?registrationCompleted');
    } else {
        header('Location: template/authentication.php?alreadyExists');
    }
} else {
    header('Location: template/authentication.php?missingFields');
}
```

Comment: No, you're only applying `empty` to `$_POST['first']`…

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['first']) && !empty($_POST['last']) && ...)`

Comment: If you need all your POST values to be set, you can write it in one go : 
`if(!empty($_POST['first'], $_POST['last'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) && ...)`

Comment: @Michael That does in fact ***not*** work. `isset` supports this, `empty` doesn't.

Comment: @deceze you're completely right, I made a mistake

Answer (score -3):

```
     $first_name = $_POST['first'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last'];
    $mail_address = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hash = hash('sha256', $password); // Password will be hashed.
    $check_1 = "pass";

 if (empty($first_name)) {
      $check_1 = "fail"; 
  }
 if (empty($last_name)) {
      $check_1 = "fail"; 
  }
 if (empty($mail_address)) {
      $check_1 = "fail"; 
  }
 if (empty($password)) {
      $check_1 = "fail"; 
  }
// other validation and sanitation stuff
if (($check_1 === "pass") && ($stmt->rowCount() == 0)) {
// add to database
}
```

you can also check user input string length and use regex to better sanitize and validate the form

Comment: You don't need to use `empty` anymore at that point, the notice it would prevent has already occurred in `$first_name = $_POST['first']`.

Comment: i know but by doing so you can let user know what's going wrong with an customized error message on every error occurring

Comment: Please read [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/). You're misusing `empty`.

Comment: that's an interesting readup

Comment: The correct place to use `isset` and `empty` is in one and only one situation: To test whether a variable that may or may not exist exists (isset) and optionally whether it's also falsey (empty). well new knowledge everyday

Comment: i would change all the `if(empty())` to `isset` on my site tomorrow ama need goto sleep now thanks you senpai ( ˘  ³ ˘) ♥